# Why doesn't Unwrap/UV Smart Project do anything?

Tags: uv, project

Whenever I press Unwrap or Smart UV Project, nothing happens. I've looked everywhere and no one seems to have the same issue. Can anyone help me?

The steps I go through:

1, click on the model I want to add a texture to.

2, go to UV Texture

3, Press A.

4, Go to Unwrap/Smart UV Project,

5, Nothing happens.

I've reloaded and uninstalled and reinstalled blender and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot of your windows including the UV Editor?

Comment: In the 3D window, are you in Edit mode and do you have everything selected ('A' key) before you try to unwrap?

Comment: I have selected all and was in Edit mode.

Comment: Ok. As @moonboots says we'll need to see a screenshot in that case. In Blender use the Window > Save Screenshot menu then edit your question and add the image to it.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time I was being an idiot and capt "A" selecting the model and not on the UV map. I've got it figured out now.